# Sort an array of optional items that holds yet another optional

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift

How can I sort an array of optionals that holds an optional NSdate?

```
class HistoryItem {
   var dateCompleted: NSDate?
}

let firstListObject = someListOfObject.last
let secondListObject = someOtherListOfObject.last
let thirdListObject = evenSomeOtherListOfObject.last //Last returns 'T?'

var array = [firstListObject , secondListObject, thirdListObject]
```

How can I sort array based on dateCompleted?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your sort function could use a combination of optional chaining and the nil
coalescing operator:

```
sort(&array) {
    (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    let t1 = item1?.dateCompleted ?? NSDate.distantPast() as! NSDate
    let t2 = item2?.dateCompleted ?? NSDate.distantPast() as! NSDate
    return t1.compare(t2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

This would sort the items on the `dateCompleted` value, and all items that
are `nil` and items with `dateCompleted == nil` are treated as "in the distant past"
so that they are ordered before all other items.

---

Update for **Swift 3** (assuming that `dateCompleted` is a `Date`):

```
array.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    let t1 = item1?.dateCompleted ?? Date.distantPast
    let t2 = item2?.dateCompleted ?? Date.distantPast
    return t1 < t2
}
```

Comment: That would do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4. if you want to keep optional values at the end, for example, use Int.max:

```
self.values.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    let value1 = item1.seconds ?? Int.max
    let value2 = item2.seconds ?? Int.max
    return value1 < value2
}
```